# Maven copy jars from network location

Tags: maven

I am a little confused about which plugin will allow me to accomplish this task. But I have some jar files sitting on a network server, and need to copy these into my project. I assume I will need to use my local keychain(osx) or provide some credentials to perform the ssh, or transfer using some other protocol. Ive looked at using maven-resources-plugin, but am unsure if this is correct.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-mstrweb-jars</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${build.location}/${version}/java/jar</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>some.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${build.location}/${version}/jars</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>somejar.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach to rely on outside resources during your build is generally discouraged, as your build will not be repeatable for people outside your local environment or even yourself if it gets updated without you noticing it.

Please consider deploying your jars to a local repository and retrieve it via a dependency or using the [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).

If you insist on using local resources, you should have a look at the [Maven Wagon Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) which offers several approaches for your problem (e.g. http/ssh).

Comment: The resources are in another repo, however the repo needs to be built before the jars are produced. So I cannot pull them down, I need to go to the server which hosts the completed builds.